# How to rename files in FTP Move Command in PHP

Tags: php, ftp, command, rename

I'm trying to move a file after a batch job e-mail has been sent into the "OLD" folder.

I have successfully determined the code to do so.  Right now the file is called `monthly_mssql`, I'm trying to rename the file to `monthly_mssql_mmmyyyy`.

With the month and year added to the end of the file I can keep track of determining which reports are for which month.  How would I edit the existing command file?

MY CODE FOR CMD FILE:

```
REM The report is generated automatically and must be sent at 9:50 AM of the first Monday of every month, file is located
REM in C:\Reports\mssql\Monthly_Stats
"C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.exe" "c:\htdocs\MultipleReport\monthly_smurfreport_email.php"
move C:\Smurf_Reports\mssql\Monthly_Stats\monthly_mssql.csv C:\Smurf_Reports\mssql\Monthly_Stats\old
```

MY CODE FOR PHP FILE:

```
 $dirpath = "C:/Reports/mssql/Monthly_Stats/";

 if ($handle = opendir($dirpath  )) 
 {

$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";


$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
        " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";



$email_message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n" .
$message_text . "\n\n";
$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))

{
    if (strpos($entry, '.csv',1))
    {
            $filepath = "";
        $filesize = 0;

        $filepath = $dirpath."".$entry; 
        $filesize = filesize ($filepath);          


        if (file_exists($filepath) && $filesize > 1)
        {
            $fileatt = $filepath;
            $fileatt_name = $entry;

            $fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream";

            $message_text .= "<P>Hi</P>";


            $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
            $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
            fclose($file);

            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

                    $email_message .=  "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
                    " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
                    //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                    $data . "\n\n";
                    $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";


        }
        $email_from = "k.j@yahoo.com";
```

//          $email_to = "k.j@yahoo.com";
            $email_to = "k.j@yahoo.com";

```
        $lastMonth = date('F-Y',strtotime('last month'));
        $email_subject = "($lastMonth) Report for MS-SQL.";

        $headers .= "From: ".$email_from."\r\n";


        echo $filepath."</br>";
    }

}

    closedir($handle);
    $ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
  }


 /*if (file_exists($filename) && $size > 228 && $EmailAdd <> "")
 {

$fileatt = $filename;

$fileatt_name = $groupname.".csv";


if ($uemail <> "")
$email_from = $uemail;

else
    $email_from = $username."@yahoo.com";


    $email_to = $email_from;

    $email_subject = " Messages for Priority '".$p."' - ".$groupname."  -      ".$displaydate;


    $headers .= "From: ".$email_from. "\r\n";


    $headers .= "Cc: ".$EmailAdd. "\r\n";

    $headers .= "Bcc: k.j@yahoo.com";

    $email_message .= "<P>Hi</P>";

    $email_message .= "<P><B>Please find attached Monthly Smurf Report         Stats."</U></B>\n";

    $email_message .= "<P><P>Thanks,<P>;

    set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

    $ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

    if ($ok)
    {
        unlink($filename);
    }
        else
        {


        $file = "C:/Reports/Operation/Daily_Stats/smtperrlog.txt";
        $fh = fopen($file, 'r+');
        $contents = fread($fh, filesize($file));
        fclose($fh);

        $stderr = fopen   ('C:/Reports/Operation/Daily_Stats/smtperrlog.txt', 'w+');
        fwrite($stderr,"");
        fclose($stderr);


        $email_fromerr = "k.j@yahoo.com";
        $email_toerr = "k.j@yahoo.com";
        $email_subjecterr = "Monthly Stats";
        $email_messageerr = $contents;
        $headerserr .= "From: ".$email_fromerr. "\r\n";

        @mail($email_toerr, $email_subjecterr, $email_messageerr,  $headerserr);

        }
  }



  */




  $message_text = "";
  $p = "";
  $EmailAdd = "";
  $headers = "";
  $counter = 0;
```

Comment: Why don't you just move the files while in the PHP script? It's not difficult. But if you really want to use batch, there's a nice answer here on how to generate the mmddyyyy string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us -- I had a snipped I made somewhere, but can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, moving it with a batch file would be unnecessary. I would move it directly in PHP with the [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) method. You can append a date at the end of the file with [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

An example of this would be:
`rename("C:\Smurf_Reports\mssql\Monthly_Stats\monthly_mssql.csv", "C:\Smurf_Reports\mssql\Monthly_Stats\old\monthly_mssql_" . date("m_Y") . ".csv");`

**Edit**

```
$cMonth = intval(date("m")); //Retrieves current month, converts to int value
$lastMonth = ($cMonth == 1 ? "12" : $cMonth - 1); //If it's January, let's set the month to December
$cYear = ($cMonth == 1 ? intval(date("Y")) - 1 : date("Y")); //If it's January, let's also set the year back by one so the dates match up

rename("C:\Smurf_Reports\mssql\Monthly_Stats\monthly_mssql.csv", "C:\Smurf_Reports\mssql\Monthly_Stats\old\monthly_mssql_" . $lastMonth . "_" . $cYear . ".csv");
```

Comment: All I have to do is just add that to the php file?

Comment: Thanks Josh this code is working fine.  I had one more question, this code is displaying the current month.  How would I get it to display 1 month previous to the current month?

Comment: Josh, do you think you can help me with a similar error that I am encountering.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969752/renaming-files-after-a-move

Comment: @KJ it looks like someone else has you covered. :) If I've solved your question would you mind marking it as such? Thanks and I hope you get everything working!